# Approach used with XOR cipher in black box scenery

Tags: algorithm-design, stream-cipher, xor

What's the approach used in cryptanalysis to make an decrypter for a simple [xor stream cipher](https://gist.github.com/growlnx/03d25f0947c96fa1253b8d5e867d008d) in a **Black Box** scenery with only the output?

Comment: None. OTP is informationally secure.

Comment: What if the user reuses the key?

Comment: The attack commonly named as crib dragging and can apply any stream cipher if the key steam is resued.